# jQuery/JavaScript - get clicked button itself in a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

I need a way to get the element pressed in a function called by that element, and disable it.

I tried using $(this), but is not working, this is my code:

```
<script>
function x(){
    $(this).prop("disabled",true);
}
<script>
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
```

```js
    function x(){
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
```

I want to avoid add and call an id, is there any way to do it?

Thank you!

-- edit --

- I can not edit the input elements, they are in another file.
- the JS code is called before the html file, and I can not edit the html file.

Comment: Just so you know, [you can avoid inline event handlers altogether.](https://jsfiddle.net/a5bfs8ke/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution 1 :**

You can simply attach a click event handler which targets the input of type button and then use `this` to target the element from where the event was invoked.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input:button").click(function()
{
  $(this).prop("disabled",true);
});
});
</script>
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' value='Disable me' />
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmLynLsg/1/

**Solution 2 :**

You can pass `this` keyword from your javascript function that would acts as a pointer to the element.

```
 <script>
function x(obj){
        $(obj).prop("disabled",true);
    }
</script>
<input type='button' onclick='x(this)' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x(this)' value='Disable me' />
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmLynLsg/2/

Comment: Thank you, it works, but sadly the JS code is called before the html file, and I can not edit it.

Comment: You can wrap the js code around $(document).ready. Updated solution.

Answer (score 2):

Its better to remove the onclick from html and do the binding inside jQuery like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="button"]').on('click', function(){
         $(this).prop('disabled', true);
  });
});
```

Check out this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HectorBarbossa/to4qe9r1/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function x(elem){
    $(elem).prop("disabled",true);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' onclick='x(this)' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x(this)' value='Disable me' />
```

Comment: Thank you, it's works, but sadly, I can not edit the input elements, they are in another file.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element with jQuery in a few ways.  In the case of your input tag, you can just say `$('input')`, but this will get all `input` elements.  If you give it an id, like `<input id="test" ...>`, then `$('#test')` would work.  Otherwise, `$('input').prop('disabled',true);` worked for me in Chrome.

Here's my full code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="test" type='button' onclick='disable()' value='Disable me' />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function disable() {
        $('#test').prop('disabled',true);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The one approach I can think of that doesn't require changing the HTML you're working with, but does involve changing the DOM you receive, is:

```
function x() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}

// selecting, and iterating over, all <input> elements with
// an in-line 'onclick' event-handler attribute:
$('input[onclick]').each(function() {

  // retrieving the contents of the 'onclick' attribute:
  var onClickFunction = $(this).attr('onclick');

  // setting the onClickFunction variable to the
  // substring of the existing value from the first
  // character to the index of the first '('
  // character, so from 'x()' to 'x' or from
  // 'function1();function2()' to 'function1'
  // (this could be worked-around, but this is
  // a simple proof-of-concept):
  onClickFunction = onClickFunction.substring(0, onClickFunction.indexOf('('));

  // if there is a function, or a variable, held as a
  // property of the window object, then:
  if (window[onClickFunction]) {
    // we remove the 'onclick' attribute, and use the
    // on() method to add the event-handler back:
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick').on('click', window[onClickFunction]);
  }
});
```

```js
function x() {
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
}

$('input[onclick]').each(function() {
  var onClickFunction = $(this).attr('onclick');
  onClickFunction = onClickFunction.substring(0, onClickFunction.indexOf('('));
  if (window[onClickFunction]) {
    $(this).removeAttr('onclick').on('click', window[onClickFunction]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
```

It's worth noting that, while the above is quite possible with jQuery, it's similarly possible with plain JavaScript:

```
function x() {
  this.disabled = true;
}

// excuse the absurdly-long variable-names; they were meant to be
// descriptive.
// here we retrieve all <input> elements with an onclick attribute:    
var inputsWithOnClick = document.querySelectorAll('input[onclick]'),

  // here we use Array.from() to turn that collection into an Array:
  arrayOfOnClickInputs = Array.from(inputsWithOnClick);

// iterating over the Array, 'input' (the first argument)
// refers to the current element of the array over which
// we're iterating:
arrayOfOnClickInputs.forEach(function(input) {

  // retrieving the contents of the 'onclick' attribute:
  var onClickFunction = input.getAttribute('onclick');

  // updating that variable to contain the substring of
  // of the attribute-value, from the first character to
  // the first occurrence of of the '(' character:
  onClickFunction = onClickFunction.substring(0, onClickFunction.indexOf('('));

  // as above:
  if (window[onClickFunction]) {

    // removing the 'onclick' attribute:
    input.removeAttribute('onclick');

    // using EventTarget.addEventListener to bind the
    // function to the click-event on the <input> element:
    input.addEventListener('click', window[onClickFunction]);
  }
});
```

```js
function x() {
  this.disabled = true;
}

var inputsWithOnClick = document.querySelectorAll('input[onclick]'),
  arrayOfOnClickInputs = Array.from(inputsWithOnClick);

arrayOfOnClickInputs.forEach(function(input) {
  var onClickFunction = input.getAttribute('onclick');
  onClickFunction = onClickFunction.substring(0, onClickFunction.indexOf('('));

  if (window[onClickFunction]) {
    input.removeAttribute('onclick');
    input.addEventListener('click', window[onClickFunction]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
<input type='button' onclick='x()' value='Disable me' />
```

The reason for these approaches is simply that, in this case, the attribute is known (`onclick`), and you wanted to use `this` within the function, which jQuery manages for you, and which `addEventListener()` also does automagically.

And I honestly couldn't think of an alternative approach to supply the `this` to where you needed it to be.

References:

- CSS:

  - [Attribute-selectors (`[attribute]`)](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`EventTarget.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).
  - [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
  - [`Element.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).
  - [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).
  - [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
  - [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
  - [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).